# Magento 1.9 Continue Button not moving to next section in onepage checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, custom

Am using `magento 1.9.3` am trying to add new steps after `shipping method` called `DELIVERY INSTRUCTIONS` i refer this link [ https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/adding-step-onepage-checkout].

I did everything same in that link.

But `DELIVERY INSTRUCTIONS` Continue button not moving to newt step. Showing some error in console like this

[image]

This my `deliveryinstructions.phtml` code

```
<form id="co-deliveryinstructions-form" action="">
    <div id="checkout-deliveryinstructions-load">
       <!-- Content loaded dynamically -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var deliveryinstructionsMethod = new DeliveryinstructionsMethod('co-deliveryinstructions-form', "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveDeliveryinstructionsMethod') ?>");
    //]]>
    </script>
    <div id="onepage-checkout-deliveryinstructions-additional-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set" id="deliveryinstructions-buttons-container">
        <p class="back-link"><a href="#" onclick="checkout.back(); return false;"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="deliveryinstructionsMethod.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
        <span id="deliveryinstructions-please-wait" class="please-wait" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Loading next step...')) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Loading next step...')) ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my second questions

Add progress title in `YOUR CHECKOUT PROGRESS`

[image]

`Skin\frontend\base\default\js\opcheckout.js`

```
setShippingMethod: function() {
        //this.nextStep();
        this.gotoSection('deliveryinstructions', true);
        //this.accordion.openNextSection(true);
    },

    //code added
    setDeliveryinstructions: function() {
        //this.nextStep();
        this.gotoSection('payment', true);
        //this.accordion.openNextSection(true);
    },
    //code added
```

How can i fix this two errors...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post your diff of `<SKIN DIRECTORY>/js/opcheckout.js>`?

Comment: @TimCieplowski update my opcheckout.js code please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer for 1st qestion. But i want to add `YOUR CHECKOUT PROGRESS` tab. 1st question answer is add new function in `skin\frontend\base\default\js\opcheckout.js`

After `shipping method` line no - `550 to 600` add following code

```
var DeliveryinstructionsMethod = Class.create();
DeliveryinstructionsMethod.prototype = {
    initialize: function(form, saveUrl){
        this.form = form;
        if ($(this.form)) {
            $(this.form).observe('submit', function(event){this.save();Event.stop(event);}.bind(this));
        }
        this.saveUrl = saveUrl;
        this.validator = new Validation(this.form);
        this.onSave = this.nextStep.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.onComplete = this.resetLoadWaiting.bindAsEventListener(this);
    },

    validate: function() {
        var methods = document.getElementsByName('deliveryinstructions');
        if (methods.length==0) {
            alert(Translator.translate('Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it. Please make necessary changes in your shipping address.').stripTags());
            return false;
        }

        if(!this.validator.validate()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i=0; i<methods.length; i++) {
            if (methods[i].checked) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        alert(Translator.translate('Please specify shipping method.').stripTags());
        return false;
    },

    save: function(){

        if (checkout.loadWaiting!=false) return;
        if (this.validate()) {
            checkout.setLoadWaiting('shipping-method');
            new Ajax.Request(
                this.saveUrl,
                {
                    method:'post',
                    onComplete: this.onComplete,
                    onSuccess: this.onSave,
                    onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
                    parameters: Form.serialize(this.form)
                }
            );
        }
    },

    resetLoadWaiting: function(transport){
        checkout.setLoadWaiting(false);
    },

    nextStep: function(transport){
        var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.evalJSON(true) || {};

        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.message.stripTags().toString());
            return false;
        }

        if (response.update_section) {
            $('checkout-'+response.update_section.name+'-load').update(response.update_section.html);
        }

        payment.initWhatIsCvvListeners();

        if (response.goto_section) {
            checkout.gotoSection(response.goto_section, true);
            checkout.reloadProgressBlock();
            return;
        }

        if (response.payment_methods_html) {
            $('checkout-payment-method-load').update(response.payment_methods_html);
        }

        checkout.setShippingMethod();
    }
};
```

And `deliveryinstructions.phtml`

```
<form id="co-deliveryinstructions-form" action="">
    <div id="checkout-deliveryinstructions-load">
       <!-- Content loaded dynamically -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var deliveryinstructionsMethod = new DeliveryinstructionsMethod('co-deliveryinstructions-form', "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveDeliveryinstructions') ?>");
    //]]>
    </script>
    <div id="onepage-checkout-deliveryinstructions-additional-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set" id="deliveryinstructions-buttons-container">
        <p class="back-link"><a href="#" onclick="checkout.back(); return false;"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="deliveryinstructionsMethod.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
        <span id="deliveryinstructions-please-wait" class="please-wait" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Loading next step...')) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Loading next step...')) ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```